# Clear the putty terminal screen from Python

Tags: python, ssh, putty

Im calling a python script from a Putty terminal on windows and I need the python script to be able to run the "clear" command in the terminal to clear the screen to make a basic UI. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Answered my own question. Use this code

```
import subrocess

subprocess.Popen("clear")
```

Comment: While that may work, all `clear` does is print a magic string that tells putty to clear the display.  That can be duplicated in Python with the right `print` statement.